# What is the difference between modules and class modules in Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I know that classes are templates for creating objects. But we cannot create objects in VBA. I am new to VBA. I don't understand the purpose of class modules in VBA

Comment: `But we cannot create objects in VBA`. Why do you think that?

Comment: You can create an instance of a class, where you cant a module, so you can say `dim c as new class1` and then say `class1.procedure1(arg1,arg2)`  and then dispose of it, `set c=nothing`

Comment: Most of the built-in things in Access are objects. So yes, you can and do have objects in VBA. You can also define your own. What you don't get is object inheritance. (Wich is a shame because it's an artificial limitation.) But you can usually get away with composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: My advice would be: If you are new, ignore class modules for now. When you get to a certain point, you will stumble over them again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can create objects in vba:

If you named your classModule: "YooClass" then you can create a object by:

```
Dim myObject as YooClass
Set myObject = new YooClass
```

I also create a non-class-module called ObjectFactory with this code:

```
Public Function Yoo(...) As YooClass
  Set Yoo= New YooClass
  Call Yoo.Init(...)
End Function
```

this works as a constructor. So I can write:

```
Dim myObject as YooClass
Set myObject = new Yoo(...)
```

or call a function directly like this

```
Call Yoo.MyFunction(...)
```

This is some kind of a "static" function-call (or as close as you can get in vba).

If you want more information about classes in VBA (or in general): There are a lot of tutorials for this with a lot of explanations and examples. Like this: https://analystcave.com/vba-vba-class-tutorial/

Answer (score 2):

Access most certainly allows you to create objects. Because Access does not support inheritance, and things like "over loading", then Access is not considered a full Object orientated programming system.

However, it has "some" parts that are considered OO (Object orientated) and you can well use such a approach. I explain in the following article as to when and why you might want to use + create objects in Access:

http://www.kallal.ca/Articles/WhyClass.html

So Access is not full OO, but it certainly has the abllity to create class objects like you would say in vb.net, or c#. I use class objects quite often now, and the above article will give you some hits as to when, and why you would want to do this in Access.